# Dask Delayed function progressively getting slower on each call. Not a memory issue

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have been working on a python script using dask to speed up the processing time.  At a high level, the script calls a dask delayed function a number of times to perform new computations.  Each time the dask delayed function is called, it has no relation to the previous call.  A simplified example of what I have is shown below.

```
def func1(list1):
    for subList in list1:
        t2 = dask.delayed(func2)(subList)
        output.append(t2)
    output = dask.compute(*output)
    return output

def func2(subList):
    #Some operations
    return tuple2 # Large Tuple with combination of lists and numpy arrays

if __name__ == '__main__':

    largeList = [..]

    for list1 in largeList:
        output = func1(list1)
        print(output)
```

I noticed that as this program was being executed, each time *func1* was called, the time to completion gradually got longer.  At first I believed this was a memory issue because the variable, *output*, is typically a large tuple with many arrays and lists.  However, looking at the Dask dashboard while the program was running, the 'Bytes Stored' plot didn't seem to max out.  I know this is a very vague example, but does anybody have any ideas about why the *func1* slows down the more times it is called? My hunch is still that the large tuple output has something to do with the issue. If so, how can I fix this problem? Any feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind to produce a full [mcve]?

Comment: Definitely, I will work on this and update soon. Thanks!